# Dozer mapping JodaTime property not working as expected

Tags: java, mapping, jodatime, dozer

I am using Dozer to map between a Document class to DocumentManagementBean class, both of my own making. Both have a property, with getters and setters, of Joda DateTime type, called dateAdded.

When Document object `d` has property `dateAdded`=x, calling `mapper.map(d, DocumentManagementBean.class)` all fields get auto-mapped correctly (since I have full control over code base I am able to get away with no dozer-config and rely simply on matching property names), EXCEPT the `dateAdded` field, where the new DocumentManagementBean `dmb` ends up with the **current** DateTime in its `dateAdded` property, instead of x from the `d` object.

I am expecting Dozer to try to call

`dmb.setDateAdded(d.getDateAdded());`

and just bring the value of dateAdded from source to target, but it seems to be creating new DateTime for dmb object an then leaving it alone.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basic problem is that Dozer creates a new blank instance of DateTime, via new DateTime(), and thats how you end up with the current date/time instead of the original one. There might be multiple solutions, I usually went with a customconverter, globally defined:

```
    <converter type="de.kba.resper.customconverter.DateTimeCustomConverter">
        <class-a>org.joda.time.DateTime</class-a>
        <class-b>org.joda.time.DateTime</class-b>
    </converter>
```

and

```
public class DateTimeCustomConverter extends DozerConverter<DateTime, DateTime> {

    public DateTimeCustomConverter() {
        super(DateTime.class, DateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertTo(final DateTime source, final DateTime destination) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new DateTime(source);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertFrom(final DateTime source, final DateTime destination) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new DateTime(source);
        }

}
```

It may overdo it, though :)

Comment: thanks, i came up with something similar but felt it's not quite right so waited if someone would perhaps provide a cleaner solution. Thanks again!

Comment: IMHO there is no sense in Dozer converter, because DateTime is immutable. So copy-by-reference solution should be preferred over custom conveter

Answer (score 14):

You probably don't need it anymore, but Dozer provides the chance to copy an object by reference, at least with the latest version (now, this version is 5.4.0). Copying by reference is what you are looking for.

```
<field copy-by-reference="true">
  <a>copyByReference</a>
  <b>copyByReferencePrime</b>
</field>
```

Documentation: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/copybyreference.html

Comment: Yep, simple solution that works great for immutables.

Answer (score 5):

Set a copy-by-reference global property in your xml file

```
    <copy-by-references>
        <copy-by-reference>
            org.joda.time.LocalDate
        </copy-by-reference>
        <copy-by-reference>
            org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
        </copy-by-reference>
    </copy-by-references>
```

Comment: Merci Pras, t'es mon héros :)

Comment: This fixed it for me, seems like the cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it but you will have to add some configuration:

```
<field>
  <a set-method="placeValue" get-method="buildValue">value</a>
  <b>value</b>  
</field>
```

Here is more information: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html

Dos some one knows how to do tins with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is that DateTime is immutable, so the deep copy cannot be done (see https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/216).

That's why you have to use a converter or copy it by reference.