# How to correctly parse Joda DateTime with SuperCSV?

Tags: supercsv

I'm attempting to parse a date from CSV like this:

```
2016-03-01
```

To a Joda DateTime with SuperCSV Dozer, like this:

```
private static final String[] FIELD_MAPPING = new String[] {"date"};

final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {
    new ParseDateTime(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD"))
};

CsvDozerBeanReader beanReader = new CsvDozerBeanReader(
    new FileReader("/path/to.csv"), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
beanReader.configureBeanMapping(MyDateHoldingBean.class, FIELD_MAPPING);
MyDateHoldingBean bean = beanReader.read(EmployeeDetails.class, processors)
```

The DateTime returned is the current date & time, *not a representation of the date read from CSV*.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `Y` is not the same as `y` - you should be using `yyyy-MM-DD` as your date format

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a step; you need to configure the Dozer mapping. Currently this must be done with a DozerBeanMapper:

```
final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {
    new ParseDateTime(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
};

DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.addMapping(new FileInputStream("/path/to/dozer.xml"));

CsvDozerBeanReader beanReader = new CsvDozerBeanReader(new FileReader("/path/to.csv"), 
    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE, mapper);
MyDateHoldingBean bean = beanReader.read(MyDateHoldingBean.class, processors)
```

where dozer.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

    <mapping>
        <class-a>org.supercsv.io.dozer.CsvDozerBeanData</class-a>
        <class-b>your.package.MyDateHoldingBean</class-b>
        <field copy-by-reference="true">
            <a>columns[0]</a>
            <b>date</b>
        </field>
   </mapping>
</mappings>
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013833/dozer-mapping-jodatime-property-not-working-as-expected)